# Vue.js change image src with a click

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, onclick

I need help with switching images. When I click on an image I want it to update from a list of sources e.g. from 4 sources with each click. So each click will update the image with the next source in the list. I am not the best with Vue, but I am learning. I have tried to do this, but haven't figured it out yet. If anyone can tell me how to do this in Vue code that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the example how you could solve image switching in vue.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      image: null,
      images: [{
          id: 1,
          src: "https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-wallpapers/download/26516/Natural-Grove-Green-Trees-Path-ipad-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg",
          alt: "Natural Grove Green Trees Path"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          src: "https://st2.depositphotos.com/1000438/6182/i/950/depositphotos_61826015-stockafbeelding-cascades-in-nationaal-park-plitvice.jpg",
          alt: "stockafbeelding cascades in nationaal park plitvice"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          src: "https://orig00.deviantart.net/6787/f/2016/104/5/6/aria_maleki___natural_view_of_waterfall_by_aria_maleki-d9yytu8.jpg",
          alt: "natural view of waterfall"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.switchImage();
  },
  methods: {
    switchImage() {
      this.image = this.images[this.index];
      this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.images.length;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: filter 0.3s ease-in;
}

.image:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img v-if="image" :key="image.id" @click="switchImage" class="image" :src="image.src" alt="image.alt">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a variable in the component's data, called image source. Then, write an onClick function, that changes this variable in the data.

Component:

```
data: () => ({
    imageSource: ''
}),
methods: {
    changeSource: function() {
        //Your source-changing code here
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<img :src="imageSource" @click="changeSource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two variables:

```
data: {
    urls: [url1, url2, url3],
    currentUrl: this.urls[0]
}
```

then you add a method which changes the `currentUrl` to the next of the array

```
methods: {
    nextUrl: () => {
        const currentIndex = urls.findIndex(url => url === currentUrl)
        this.currentUrl = urls[currentIndex++]
    }
}
```

in the html you attach everything to the image

```
<img :src="currentUrl" @click="nextUrl()">
```